# How to use every plot with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the paragraph about gnuplot in the pgfmanual, I read this :

> The following styles influence the plot: `/tikz/every plot`  (style,
>   initially empty) This style is installed in each plot, that is, as if
>   you always said `plot[every plot,...]` This is most useful for globally
>   setting a prefix for all plots by saying:
>
> ```
>  \tikzset{every plot/.style={prefix=plots/}}
> ```

I try this with no succes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4,every plot/.style={green,ultra thick}]
  \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
  \draw plot[id=x]   function{x}    node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
  \draw plot[id=sin] function{sin(x)}      node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
  \draw plot[id=exp] function{0.05*exp(x)} node[right] {$f(x) = \frac{1}{20} \mathrm e^x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the `color` options are part of the `\draw` command, they won't be seen as options passed to the `plot` command.  So the only things that can go into  `every plot/.style` are actual plot options, e.g. the `parametric` option, the `domain` option, the `samples` option, all the mark options, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4,every plot/.style={mark=ball,samples=5}]
  \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
  \draw plot[id=x]   function{x}    node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
  \draw plot[id=sin] function{sin(x)}      node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
  \draw plot[id=exp] function{0.05*exp(x)} node[right] {$f(x) = \frac{1}{20} \mathrm e^x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]